# Search filter repo for react-native project

Tags: react-native, github

I have a chatting app called Chatous.

It has a function of choose the person to talk. I could call this function like `search filter`, `tag filter` or `parameter filter`.

**I can't find any similar screens on github**.

Hope you can help! Here are some screens of what I'm talking about:-

[image: https://64.media.tumblr.com/4b67495c10b425288d83ed1cb2d66a8b/tumblr_inline_p8g94ktTS31qac0f9_500.png]
[image: https://mobile.softpedia.com/screenshots/chatous-android_3.jpg]

I wish anyone of you can help me to find a repo, because I don't know how to google it correctly.

Comment: Better make your own code by using libaries https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-search-filter  you can find many types of libaries just google it